# CentOS installation rpms 5.5 vs. 6.4

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, migration

I am migrating from CentOS 5.5 to 6.4 and have a custom installation that installs specific RPMs.  The problem I running into is that some RPMs from CentOS 5.5 are no longer in the 6.4 distribution, so my make fails because it can't find a rpm in the source distribution.

Is there a good way to determine what RPMs I might need from 6.4 to replace the missing RPMs that were in 5.5??  Trying to figure out a good way to do this so I don't miss anything.

So far, I've tried looking at the files and information for the RPMs in 5.5 and search for similar information in the RPMs for 6.4. This seems like a bad idea and hasn't really helped me out.  I would think that there is a better way to do this???

Here is the list of CentOS 5.5 RPMs that are missing in 6.4:

- SysVinit-2.86-15.el5.i386.rpm
- anacron-2.3-45.el5.centos.i386.rpm
- apmd-3.2.2-5.i386.rpm
- aspell-0.60.3-7.1.i386.rpm
- beecrypt-4.1.2-10.1.1.i386.rpm
- bluez-gnome-0.5-5.fc6.i386.rpm
- bluez-utils-3.7-2.2.el5.centos.i386.rpm
- cadaver-0.22.3-4.el5.i386.rpm
- centos-release-notes-5.5-0.i386.rpm
- chkfontpath-1.10.1-1.1.i386.rpm
- dhcdbd-2.2-2.el5.i386.rpm
- dhcpv6-client-1.0.10-18.el5.i386.rpm
- dmalloc-5.3.0-3.i386.rpm
- fbset-2.1-22.i386.rpm
- firstboot-tui-1.4.27.8-1.el5.centos.i386.rpm
- gnupg-1.4.5-14.i386.rpm
- htmlview-4.0.0-2.el5.noarch.rpm
- ibmasm-3.0-9.i386.rpm
- ifd-egate-0.05-15.i386.rpm
- ipsec-tools-0.6.5-13.el5_3.1.i386.rpm
- irda-utils-0.9.17-2.fc6.i386.rpm
- kudzu-1.2.57.1.24-1.el5.centos.i386.rpm
- libFS-1.0.0-3.1.i386.rpm
- libgssapi-0.10-2.i386.rpm
- libjpeg-6b-37.i386.rpm
- libtermcap-2.0.8-46.1.i386.rpm
- libvolume_id-095-14.21.el5.i386.rpm
- mkinitrd-5.1.19.6-61.i386.rpm
- mktemp-1.5-23.2.2.i386.rpm
- nash-5.1.19.6-61.i386.rpm
- nss_ldap-253-25.el5.i386.rpm
- oddjob-libs-0.27-9.el5.i386.rpm
- pam_ccreds-3-5.i386.rpm
- pam_smb-1.1.7-7.2.1.i386.rpm
- pkinit-nss-0.7.6-1.el5.i386.rpm
- portmap-4.0-65.2.2.1.i386.rpm
- python-elementtree-1.2.6-5.i386.rpm
- python-sqlite-1.1.7-1.2.1.i386.rpm
- rhpl-0.194.1-1.i386.rpm
- rng-utils-2.0-1.14.1.fc6.i386.rpm
- setarch-2.0-1.1.i386.rpm
- slrn-0.9.8.1pl1-1.2.2.i386.rpm
- specspo-13-1.el5.centos.noarch.rpm
- sysklogd-1.4.1-46.el5.i386.rpm
- system-config-securitylevel-tui-1.6.29.1-5.el5.i386.rpm
- termcap-5.5-1.20060701.1.noarch.rpm
- util-linux-2.13-0.52.el5_4.1.i386.rpm
- vixie-cron-4.1-77.el5_4.1.i386.rpm
- xorg-x11-filesystem-7.1-2.fc6.noarch.rpm
- xorg-x11-xfs-1.0.2-4.i386.rpm
- yum-updatesd-0.9-2.el5.noarch.rpm

Comment: remove the version numbers.

Comment: Remove the numbers and you'll typically have to go through these lists by hand. I've never seen a automatic way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the version numbers and you'll typically have to go through these lists by hand. I've never seen a automatic way to do it.

My usual tactic is to take that list minus the numbers and then get the list of packages from the next versions repo, and side-by-side diff them or use `meld`.

RPM Tools you'll likely use in this endeavor:

- repoquery
- repotrack
- rpm
- yum

I've written up a number of posts on the site that detail the use of [repoquery](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A7453+repoquery). Look to those for potential ways to use it. Also a good tutorial on it's usage, titled: [Centos 6/RHEL using Repoquery and Yum commands](http://minimallinux.blogspot.com/2012/11/centos-6rhel-using-repoquery-and-yum.html).

#### Cleaning up the package list

You can use this command to truncate your list of packages so they don't include the version numbers:

```
$ sed 's/-[0-9]\+.*//' file.txt
```

#### Example

Sample file.

```
$ head -5 file.txt 
SysVinit-2.86-15.el5.i386.rpm
anacron-2.3-45.el5.centos.i386.rpm
apmd-3.2.2-5.i386.rpm
aspell-0.60.3-7.1.i386.rpm
beecrypt-4.1.2-10.1.1.i386.rpm
```

Sample run.

```
$ sed 's/-[0-9]\+.*//' file.txt | head -5
SysVinit
anacron
apmd
aspell
beecrypt
```

Comment: This helped out a ton..Going through the list by hand now to determine what is needed with CentOS 6.4.